# How do I distinguish a automatic redirect from a user intended redirect (a click)

Tags: google-chrome, redirect, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension that tries to protect users from being redirected to malicious web pages.

When a user visits a shady domain like "fa**ec**book.com" he will be redirected to another page but this was not his intention. When a user intends to be redirected to another page this will mostly be due to a click (f.e. a click on a hyperlink: `<a href="http://foobar.com">`)

How can I distinguish the two types?

Currently I'm inspecting the details from the redirects using this code from my extension but I can't find anything to distinguish one from the other:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRedirect.addListener(
  function(details) {
    console.log(details);
  },
  {urls: ['<all_urls>']});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trigger an event only when the user changes the URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42132733/how-to-trigger-an-event-only-when-the-user-changes-the-url)

Comment: Related: [Prevent initial webRequest prior to redirecting new tab/window only when opened by user clicking link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41131300)

Comment: @Makyen Your first link looks very interesting and helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless Chrome specifically makes this information available, then you can't directly detect whether a request is the result of a redirect or a direct request resulting from clicking on a hyperlink or typing the URL into the browser. Both are standard browser requests. (You can potentially check the HTTP referer for direct links and perhaps to see where the link originated - but this is likely to be unreliable.)

IMO you would need to check for the redirect *before* it actually happens. In other words by scanning the previous response. But there could be 3 flavours of redirect:

1. HTTP redirect: check for a 3xx status code and `Location:` HTTP response header.
2. META Refresh: Scan the HTML `head` section for this tag. (Although it could be added late with JS?)
3. JavaScript Redirect: This could be very difficult to spot unless you somehow process the JavaScript in a sandbox first?